# plone Assertion error in themes

Tags: plone

Iam new to Plone. I installed Plone 4 and i have gone through http://noenieto.com/blog/theming-plone-4 and created theme product.

When i run ./bin/buildout,
iam getting the error as

```
    Develop: '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/src/plonetheme.hanging'
error in plonetheme.hanging setup command: Distribution contains no modules or packages for namespace package 'plonetheme'
While:
  Installing.
  Processing develop directory '/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/src/plonetheme.hanging'.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 417, in install
    installed_develop_eggs = self._develop()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 657, in _develop
    zc.buildout.easy_install.develop(setup, dest)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 895, in develop
    *args) == 0
AssertionError
```

Can anyone help me to rectify this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module or package for namespace package 'plonetheme', e.g.:

```
mkdir -p src/plonetheme.hanging/plonetheme/hanging
touch src/plonetheme.hanging/plonetheme/__init__.py
touch src/plonetheme.hanging/plonetheme/hanging/__init__.py
```

`src/plonetheme.hanging/plonetheme/__init__.py` should contain something like:

```
from pkg_resources import declare_namespace
declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working now.But it throws a warning.WARNING: plonetheme is a namespace package, but its __init__.py does
not declare_namespace(); setuptools 0.7 will REQUIRE this!

Comment: That's what: from pkg_resources import declare_namespace
declare_namespace(__name__) is for…